# a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' XTEA Algorithm

Tags: python, string, typeerror, xtea

I have a big problem and I need your help. 
I have to encrypt my data with the xtea algorithm. I'm a completely beginner in python so I don't know any further.

I put my two hashed passwords and some data together. Because the my xtea algorithm don't want to have any strings in it I encoded it. (Encode 'utf-8' doesnt work here)

```
datas = macpassword_hashed_versch + tea_password + txt_neu
data_endi = str.encode(datas)
normales_password = normales_password.encode('utf-8')
data_en = xtea_algo(data_endi, normales_password)
```

Here is my xtea:

```
def xtea_algo(message, p):
    key = p
    text = message * 8
    x = new(key, mode=MODE_CFB, IV="12345678")
    c = x.encrypt(text)
    return c
```

After this it is giving me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     Steganographie.py", line 77, in 
>       data_en = xtea_algo(data_endi, normales_password)
>
> Steganographie.py", line 23, in xtea_algo
>       c = x.encrypt(text)
>
> lib\site-packages\pep272_encryption__init__.py", line 188, in
>   encrypt
>       encrypted_iv = self.encrypt_block(self.key, self._status)
>
> lib\site-packages\xtea__init__.py", line 230, in encrypt_block
>       struct.unpack(self.endian + "2L", block),
>
> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

I controlled the types in my giving parameters and every object type is "bytes"
:( Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: I guess that the IV must be byte-like, too.

Comment: You earned some Chocolate Mr.! That helped. Thank you so much! :)